# Set UserForm5 Background to match a ClickedON Cell Font Backgroun/Fill Color?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to match the background color of my UserForm5 to match the font background/fill color of any cell i (target) click on.... what would tbe vba code be to do this.. Thanks..

New to this, early learning days. Andy Moore

Comment: What did you already try and what specific problems are you having with getting this set up?  There's an event raised when the user makes a range selection - you can capture that to figure out the color you need to use.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.selectionchange

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally it's best to provide more detail about the specific issues you're facing when posting here, but since I already have this:

In the `ThisWorkbook` code module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    SetFormColor Target.Cells(1) 'uses the first cell if >1 selected
End Sub
```

In a regular code module:

```
Option Explicit

Private f As frmInfo 'holds a reference to the opened form

Sub OpenForm()
    Set f = New frmInfo
    f.Show False                            '#show non-modally#
    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then   'initial color?
        SetFormColor Selection.Cells(1)
    End If
End Sub

Sub SetFormColor(c As Range)
    If f Is Nothing Then Exit Sub    'exit if no open form
    f.BackColor = c.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color 'DisplayFormat also includes Conditional Formatting
End Sub
```